# Beamer blocks with image background

Tags: beamer

I'm using a blackboard style beamer that works really well. But I want to try and block the text up a bit. I'd like it to look like chalk shading like this:
Like these: https://stock.adobe.com/uk/images/smears-are-chalk-vintage-textures-on-a-blackboard-high-resolution-image-pastel-shades-of-brushes-template-for-registration-of-stickers-banners-posters-stock-vector/152197264
Then I can set the text color to the blackboard colour so it looks like inverse.

Any ideas how I can format blocks to have an image background?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `tcolorbox` inner theme to add a background image to the block:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useinnertheme{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{
  enhanced,
  frame style image={example-image-duck},
  opacityback=0,
  opacitybacktitle=0
}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    \begin{block}{title}
    content
  \end{block}
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]